# html link to anchor in local file

Tags: html

I would like to create a link with anchor, which references and HTMl element of a local html file by id as follows:

```html
<a href="local_file.html#anchor_id">Anchor link</a>
```

But it seems that it does not work, while the link to the local file without an anchor works fine:

```html
<a href="local_file.html"></a>
```

I tried right click and "Open in a new tab", then it worked fine. But left click does not work.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Is `anchor_id` in `#anchor_id` unique in the page?

Comment: What do you mean by "local file"? Are you linking to a file in the user's file system?

Comment: works for me with `<a id="anchor_id">Here</a>` in the page if anchor_id is unique when I link `<a href="file:///C:/Temp/test.html#anchor_id">Go</a>` Tested in Chrome, Edge and Firefox  - Also works if the file are in the same folder and I have `<a href="test.html#anchor_id">Go</a>`

Comment: Yes, it is unique, it is a file in the local system. Is it related to the fact that I was also using a local file to link to another local file?

Comment: No. I just made two plain html files in the same folder files linking to each other. No problem at all

Comment: Ok, that is weird.

Comment: very. Can you post the link and the anchor in your question?

Comment: @shrinklemma which browser do you use for testing it? Did you try a different one?

Comment: This may be helpful: I just tried right click and "Open in the new tab", then it works. But left click, nothing happens.

Comment: Thanks for editing.

Comment: I tried microsoft edge and chrome, neither works.